# magickwand for php extension fails at compilation

Tags: php, debian, imagemagick

I'm using Debian 6 x64. I'm having the same problem as this guy: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=18459

I tried magickwand for php in 1.0.8 and 1.0.9 version with every version available of imagemagick in the mirrors. I followed the normal compilation process (the rebuild of the php source) in this case, php-5.4.0 (I also tried php-5.3.8).

With magickwand 1.0.9 and imagemagick 6.7.4-2 I have this error on the make process:

```
ext/magickwand/.libs/magickwand.o: In function `zif_magickgetimageendian':    
/home/source/php-5.4.0/ext/magickwand/magickwand.c:5764: undefined reference to     `MagickGetImageEndian'
ext/magickwand/.libs/magickwand.o:(.data.rel.ro+0x2a88): undefined reference to     `    zif_magicksetimageendian'
```

I have 3 servers with almost the same configuration, it works without a problem on one of them but for the other two the compilation fails. I compared the configuration files and make files of php and imagemagick and all is equal with one exception. In the two that fail, they are grabbing the xml2-config from another path. I also tried to compile with the same makefiles as the server that worked and the two that failed.

Why might my make commands be failing?

Comment: You can compare the installed packages at both servers. On the server that works # dpkg -la > /tmp/works. On the server that does not work: #dpkg -la > /tmp/doesnotwork. Then copy both files to same dir and: # diff doesnotwork works. Then install missing packages on the server that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Support for php > 5.3 was added recently to Magickwand for php; Changelog excerpt follows:

2011-11-13 1.0.9-0 Herve Seignole

```
- PHP > 5.3.0 does not define safe mode or php_checkuid (see
- http://php.net/manual/en/features.safe-mode).
- Use zend_function_entry rather than function_entry.
```